# Method name cannot be separated from its opening parenthesis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

### Cannot be rendered

```
    <p>
        Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor
        (x => x.Name)
    </p>
```

### Rendered

```
    <p>
        Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(
        x => x.Name)
    </p>
```

Why can't we separate the method name from the opening parenthesis `(` such that each with its own line?

Is there a trick to bypass this feature (or possibly a bug)?

Comment: Why?  Razor is about navigating the line between HTML and C# and it has to take whitespace into account. I'm sure you can do this in ASPX between `<% %>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you're in a *template*, not a `*.cs` file. Razor, the template rendering engine used by MVC, parses the template to pull out pieces of text that look like code to it and executes those, but it's not perfect, and it can't always catch every scenario.

In particular, here, the `@` prefix directly before a method call, tells Razor to read until the call string ends, i.e. with the `)`, or until it reaches the end of the line. Since, it never gets a complete call string on the line, it fails.

Comment: Sorry, should it be regarded as a bug?

Comment: No. It's not a bug. It's just how Razor, and pretty much any other template rendering engine to an extent, works. The difference is that here, executable code has to be parsed out of a plain-text source whereas in a `*.cs` file, it's all code. That means you can't do all the fancy formatting you might like in your Razor view. Sometimes, you're just going to butt up against the inherent limitations of this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to tell Razor that the whole thing is a code block

`Your name: @(Html.TextBoxFor
        (x => x.Name))`